# How to load SNAPPY format compressed parquet data from Google Storage bucket to BigQuery table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, parquet, snappy

I am trying to load a Big Query table from data exported to GS bucket. This data is in Parquet format and compressed as SNAPPY. I want to assign custom partitioning schema.

```
bq load --source_format=PARQUET  --hive_partitioning_mode=CUSTOM --hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix=gs://dummy_bucket/test_table/{refresh_date:DATE} test_ds.test_table gs://dummy_bucket/test_table/*
```

Execution of above command is giving me error like-

> Waiting on bqjob_r1ed7792315a020fc_00000177ef24ff26_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
> BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'project_dev:bqjob_r1ed7792315a020fc_00000177ef24ff26_1': Error while reading data, error message: Input file is not in Parquet format.
> Failure details:

- query: Cannot add hive partitioning to table
  test_table_bfcbdfe3_665a_4472_b0e9_8617f131b1ab_source --
  table creation from underlying uri failed.. Underlying error: Input
  file is not in Parquet format..

Comment: Did you try with only one file? Without partitioning mode? with .snappy extension to your file?

Comment: Tried it, still same error-
table creation from underlying uri failed.. Underlying error: Input
file is not in Parquet format..

Comment: Why does the file path in your command does not contain the [".parquet"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#parquet_schemas) extension?